Behavior of a capacitor at start-up
At startup, a fully discharged capacitor behaves like a short circuit, leading to a high surge current. However, why does it exhibit this behavior initially? Upon reasoning, I concluded that during startup, the voltage across the capacitor is zero, causing it to act as a short circuit and allowing high currents to flow due to its low equivalent series resistance (ESR). Yet, capacitors possess a dielectric material between their plates, normally involving an open circuit. How, then, can it behave as short circuit at the initial time? Shouldn't the equivalent resistance of the capacitor seen by the source equal to the sum of both the resistance from the dielectric gap and the ESR? I know that the last sentence is uncorrect, but someone can me explain why?

DO you know what is "displacement current" ? 4th Maxwell equation. https://www.maxwells-equations.com/ampere/amperes-law.php

I'm sorry to have to downvote this, but I literally just typed "behaviour of a capacitor" into Google, and got the first link as a general explanation in a circuit, and the second link as a  detailed explanation involving electric fields and the plates charging. Please, use a search engine before asking questions.

Just think of capacitors conforming to this equation (the basic capacitor equation): -
$$i_C = C\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$
So, the faster you apply the voltage (a larger value of \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$), the more current is taken. If you have a 1 farad capacitor and you apply a ramping voltage of 1 volt per second, the current taken is 1 amp. It will continue to take 1 amp whilst the voltage is ramping up.
When the voltage goes to a stable value, current no longer flows into the capacitor. If you then ramped the voltage down at 1 volt per second, 1 amp would flow out of the capacitor and into the ramping down voltage source.
Understand this first before moving onto ESR and dielectric losses.

Initially, the capacitor has zero volts across it, and contains no charge. \$Q = VC\$, where Q is the charge in Coulombs, V is the voltage in volts, and C is the capacitance in Farads.
If you want to change the voltage on the capacitor to some other voltage, it will hold some other charge. To change the charge requires a current for a certain time, \$It = Q\$, where \$I\$ is the current in amps, and t the time in seconds.
If you try to change that charge in a short time, you'll need a high current. If you try to do it in a very short time indeed, then the resistance of the wires in the circuit, and the residual resistance inside the capacitor will play a part in limiting how large a current can flow.

The instantaneous impedance of a circuit element is the instantaneous voltage across the element divided by the instantaneous current through the element. Any circuit element that has current flowing through it, but no voltage across it has 0 instantaneous impedance. When a capacitor is uncharged, it has 0 voltage across it, but one may have an instantaneous current. Thus, it has an instantaneous impedance of 0, just like a short circuit.
The instantaneous current through the capacitor will, however, cause the voltage across the capacitor to rise, either quickly or slowly, depending upon the capacitance of the capacitor and the magnitude of the current. Thus, although an uncharged capacitor behaves (instantaneously) similar to a short circuit, it doesn't stay that way. In fact, when the capacitor is charged to whatever voltage the supply will charge it to, the capacitor then behaves, not like a short circuit, but like an open circuit.
Here is a a typical waveform for a 100 uF capacitor charged by a 5 V supply, where the internal resistance of the supply, in combination with the effective series resistance of the capacitor and any wiring resistance is 100 m\$\Omega\$.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

If we add a little parasitic inductance to the circuit, the rate at which current to its peak will be lower, and the peak current will be less.

simulate this circuit


capacitors possess a dielectric material between their plates, normally involving an open circuit. How, then, can it behave as short circuit at the initial time?

The current through the dielectric is what is known as displacement current. If the dielectric is space, (or air) displacement current is just the rate of change of the electric field between the plates of the capacitor. If the dielectric is something like ceramic, or the oxide layer of an electrolytic capacitor, the there is a current due to polarization of the atoms. Atoms consist of negative electrons and positive nuclei. The atoms become distorted in an electric field, with the nuclei being pulled toward the negative potential, and the electrons being pulled toward the positive potential. Although the movement of these charges is extremely small, there number of atoms is enormous. The net effect is that large currents (actual movement of charges) can flow.
[Note that this polarization current is sometimes called "displacement" current, and sometimes not. This "displacement" of charges is how "displacement current" originally got its name, but "displacement current" eventually came to mean changes in the electric field. It is one of those oddities of history like electrons flowing in the opposite direction to conventional current.]

Profound answer... I think the simplest intuitive explanation is that these are two voltage sources - original and copy - connected to each other. Depending on the voltage of the copy source - different or equal to the original, it behaves as a short circuit or an open circuit.

You connect a certain voltage between the capacitor plates. Or at least try to do it by inserting a voltage source which has a certain idle state output voltage + some series resistance and inductance.
The distance between the plates is quite short, so there can be a strong electric field between the plates (that's measured as volts per a meter). It pushes the electrons in metal and you see as high current as possible with the existing source voltage and the total resistance and inductance of the parts in the circuit. The effect of the electric field spreads along metal which makes the wires useful. Historically it's called electric influence.
Also the inductance of the parts reduce the initial current, because it forces the current to change gradually. Stepwise current jump is physically impossible due the induction.

Basic idea

At startup, a fully discharged capacitor behaves like a short circuit, leading to a high surge current.

This is not just a specific electrical phenomenon; it is a concept. It refers to the case when in an accumulating element a flow-like quantity changes but the pressure-like quantity remains constant. This resembles the case where a non-accumulating element has zero resistance; hence the analogy of a capacitor to a short circuit.
How to reveal it

However, why does it exhibit this behavior initially?

To understand this phenomenon in a general way, we do not need a strict theoretical knowledge of capacitor nature. All we need is to imagine that "something" flows and accumulates in a kind of container (reservoir, tank). Because the "flowing thing" has nowhere to go, its pressure (level, volume) slowly begins to rise.
For the purpose of this "very intuitive explanation", I have used two didactic techniques that I have drawn from my experience with students:

I have driven the element under study not by a voltage source but by a current source. This is much more convenient for studying over time because the processes develop slowly.

I have represented the uncharged capacitor of extremely large capacity by a voltage source with zero voltage. This allows us to DC sweep it.


Unipolar capacitor model
Let's follow step by step the electrical manifestations of the "capacitor short circuit" phenomenon.
No short circuit
If a current flows and enters a point (the input of the element), we expect the potential of this point to rise... and it actually starts to rise because the element has some resistance (Ohm's law, V = I.R). From this we conclude that this is not a short circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

True short circuit
If the resistance is zero, no matter how much we increase the current, the potential will remain zero. We call this a "short circuit" (Ohm's law, V = I.R = I.0 = 0), "real short" or a "real ground".

simulate this circuit

Virtual short circuit
Another way to explain why there is voltage in the first case above, is because the element is not accumulating. However, if this point is the input of an element that has the property to accumulate charge (or more precisely, potential energy), and its capacitance is large enough, the current will flow but the potential will stay zero. This gives us the illusion of a "short circuit" but  it is not real; it is virtual. Note that in the schematic below, an "infinitely" large capacitance is simulated with a voltage source C with zero voltage that will never change.

simulate this circuit

So what is characteristic here is that the "thing" (let's say "charge" here) enters but does not leave the element; it accumulates. At the first moment the potential not change, but after a long enough time it will start to change. If the capacitance is infinitely large, it will happen after infinite time... i.e., never... So the "real short" is something permanent in time while the "capacitor virtual short" is only a momentary illusion at the beginning.
Bipolar capacitor model
Representing the capacitor as just a tank is a simplified model used in electrostatics that corresponds to an open circuit. Here, the processes are one-time - a current flows between two points until the difference in their potentials equalizes and the current stops. In this sense, the capacitor has only an input (like a Leyden jar).

Yet, capacitors possess a dielectric material between their plates, normally involving an open circuit. How, then, can it behave as short circuit at the initial time?

In circuits, we work with bipolar devices where current enters through one terminal and exits through the other to form a closed circuit. How, then, is the illusion of a "short circuit* obtained?
In this case, we can imagine the capacitor as two tanks side by side. The "moving thing" constantly enters one of them and accumulates in it. At the same time, something like this "thing" keeps coming out of the other tank, and we think it is gone through the dielectric barrier (it seems to me that there was such a circus focus in the past). Here is an attempt to represent a "bipolar capacitor" by pairing two "unipolar capacitors".

simulate this circuit

@Simon Fitch, I want to ask you about the difference between voltage and potential because I notice you persistently use the latter. Me too in the past before I started writing in English. Then we here  knew that "voltage is a potential difference" which really sounds better than "voltage is a voltage difference between two voltages". Or, we talk about potential when we have only one point and the second (ground) is implied, and we talk about voltage when we have two "floating" points. So now I am tempted to start expressing myself this way again but I am not sure. Here is an attempt…

Current is measured in amperes. So is ampacity (current carrying capacity). But current is not the same thing as ampacity. Similarly, the difference in electric field potential is measured in volts. But so is EMF. Those two things are related, but they are not the same, even though both are measured in volts. In my mind, "voltage" just means some quantity that is measured in "volts", but doesn't further specify what that quantity represents physically. Hence, voltage is ambiguous.

@Math Keeps Me Busy, Thanks for your responsiveness, although I'm having a hard time following your point. It's one of those things that we have a very good intuition about and use without thinking. But a problem arises when we have to communicate with other people and then we have to find the right word. The language barrier is another difficulty. In English "voltage" is predominantly used, but it seems to me that "potential" gives a subtle nuance of this quantity.

The term "voltage" is commonly used, but it is ambiguous. It merely means something that is measured in volts. There are multiple distinct physical phenomena that are measured in volts. Calling them all "voltage", obscures their differences. If electric potential difference is meant, then the term "potential difference" is preferable. (Although there are also other potentials fields, like gravitation, but since we are in the field of EE, it is clear that electric potential difference is meant.)

@Math Keeps Me Busy, I see... But isn't the reference point an essential feature to distinguish the two terms?  That is, potential is the voltage referenced to ground, and voltage is the difference between two potentials? To use voltage when it is floating and potential when it is grounded?
